# Do we need the [negative-margin]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

We currently have a [negative-margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/negative-margin) tag. This tag is used in all places where [margin] would also work, and this tag describes the MVCE of the OP, instead of what the actual problem is.

You cannot be an expert in [negative-margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/negative-margin), without being a expert in [margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margin)

[negative-margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/negative-margin) has 104 questions and 2 followers.